# Laravel Postman Issue

Tags: laravel, postman

I tried to find the solution but i failed, let me know if there is similar question Thanks

Laravel 5.7

Postman updated version

When i want to add url parameter to wildcard url API

url =  `Route::get('/store/{id}', 'StoreController@show');`

when i put the url in postman with /{id} like this /1 it work

but when i click on parameters on postman it give me this url

/?id=1

which result the 404 Error

what i am missing ?

Thanks

Postman SS

[image]

Comment: Add a snapshot of your attempt in postman

Comment: @vivek_23 Done sir.

Comment: Remove the id=1 from the params. Just add /1 as you did initially. The {id} will be understood by Laravel properly.

Comment: but i need to add parameter from postman in url properly i did this before in older version of laravel it worked but this time i dont know whats the issue.

Comment: This is because `id` is not exactly a GET parameter.

Comment: So just keep it `/API/store/1`.

Comment: it also doesn't work with POST method already tested

Comment: POST is not a road blocker here. Change request method in your Postman from GET to POST and make sure your Laravel route also listens to this on Post method, like `Route::post `

Answer (score 0):

**TL,DR** Enter your URL as: `http://example.com/path/:id` into Postman and you can see the place to enter the correct parameter. You won't be able to edit the parameter key here.

[image]

### Explaination

The parameters in your route file are **path parameters**.

The parameters in the *Params* tab of Postman are **query strings** parameters by default.

So, in your case, if the full URL is: `http://example.com/id/1?id=2` and you have `/id/{id}` route registered:

- `1` is the value of the `id` path parameter.
- `2` is the value of the `id` query string parameter.

Laravel use only path parameters when resolving routes and the query string is ignored. In this example, only this part of URL `http://example.com/id/1` is considered when routes are resolved, the `?id=2` is ignored.